# Merging columns from separate tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 2 separate select statements that both return similar information

```
SELECT PlayerName, SUM(Field1) + SUM(Field2) AS Power
FROM (SELECT PlayerName, Field1, Field2
    FROM Plays INNER JOIN Creep ON Plays.Id = Creep.Id
    ) tmp 
GROUP BY PlayerName
```

Which returns

```
-- PlayerName         |Power       
-- ----------------------------
-- Player1            |4         
-- Player2            |5
```

I have a separate call

```
SELECT PlayerName, SUM(Field3) AS Weakness
FROM (SELECT PlayerName, Field3
    FROM Plays INNER JOIN WeakCreep ON Plays.Id = WeakCreep.Id
    ) tmp2
GROUP BY PlayerName
```

Which returns a similar result

```
-- PlayerName         |Weakness      
-- ----------------------------
-- Player1            |1         
-- Player2            |3
```

I am trying to find a way to produce

```
-- PlayerName         |Power        |Weakness     
-- ---------------------------------------
-- Player1            |4            |1      
-- Player2            |5            |3
```

It feels like I've tried every variation of JOIN and UNION but I cannot find a way to produce the combine results.  Any suggestions as to how to combine the 2 queries?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried and why the result was wrong?

Comment: Does a player always have entries in bother CREEP and WEAKCREEP?  If not, how do you want to apply the join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT PlayerName, SUM(Field1) + SUM(Field2) AS Power, SUM(Field3) AS Weakness
FROM(SELECT t1.PlayerName, t2.Field1, t2.Field2, t3.Field3
     FROM 
     Plays t1,Creep t2,WeakCreep t3
     where 
     t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Id = t3.Id
     GROUP BY t1.PlayerName, t2.Field1, t2.Field2, t3.Field3)
     GROUP BY PlayerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using left joins

```
SELECT  p.PlayerName, 
    SUM(c.Field1) + SUM(c.Field2) AS Power , 
    SUM(w.Field3) AS Weakness   
FROM    Plays p , Creep c , WeakCreep w
where   p.Id = c.Id(+)
and p.Id = w.Id(+)
group by p.PlayerName
```